# Pull out div from right of screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, hidden, slide

Pull out a div from the left?  Easy as pie.  Pull it out from the right?  Not so much.

I am looking for a div to be hidden offscreen but connected to a small tag on screen.  When the user clicks the tag, out slides the whole div.  This is pretty basic from the left using jQuery and CSS.  From the right though, a user can just scroll over to see the "hidden" div!

Here is what I want ([http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv)) except instead of the div being **partially** hidden offscreen-left, I want it partially hidden offscreen-right.

Here is what I've tried so far (http://jsfiddle.net/LU8En/), and obviously it doesn't work since one can just scroll to the right.

The problem with using animate (or slide or toggle drop) is that I don't want the whole div to just disappear/appear, I want that little bit to be present.

Comment: The second jsfiddle doesn't seem to match your description; the div is still pulling out from the left-hand side.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, I must've copied it before I started making the changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/3/

**Note, the example below does not work with newer versions of jQuery, read on below for an example that does.**

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

Change everything from left to right, then reposition the clickme div and the text content.

Also, give the body an `overflow-x: hidden` to prevent the horizontal scrollbar.

---

A few minor updates makes it compatible with the latest version:

```
$(function () {
    var rightVal = -280; // base value
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        rightVal = (rightVal * -1) - 280; // calculate new value
        $(this).parent().animate({right: rightVal + 'px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2968/

Comment: Ahhh, overflow!  Thank you for being both so right and so fast!

Comment: Old post but maybe someone will see this. This example doesn't work on never JQuery. Any quick fix to solve that?

Comment: Yes, replace toggle with click. .toggle doesn't bind click events anymore.

Answer (score 0):

May need to do:

```
body,html { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Just body without ",html" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and link as well might be it will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/avinashMaddy/4bs3zp44/

```
<div id="slideout">
   <div id="slidecontent">
       Yar, there be dragonns herre!
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clickme">
    &nbsp;
</div>



<script>
  $(function () {
     $(".clickme").toggle(function () {
       $("#slideout").animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
      }, function () {
    $("#slideout").animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
   });
  });
</script>
```