# Slide out div using jquery

Tags: jquery

Recently I found a solution to slide out div on click in [stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422005/pull-out-div-from-right-of-screen/) .

They posted the link `jsfiddle.net/LU8En/`.

In the jsfiddle answer they used jquery 1.7.2. Its not working with jquery 1.9.1. I don't know the reason..? Any Idea..?

Comment: This is not a proper question. You should post a comment in the mentioned question.

Comment: since we are just posting links: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions should give you what you need. However, this is still not a question that should be asked here.

Comment: you should use jquery UI

Comment: Yeah I know but they deleted my comment in mentioned questions. I don't know what's the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/577/)

```
$(function () {
  $("#clickme").click(function () {
    if($(this).parent().css("right") == "-280px"){
    $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
  }
  else {
    $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
  }
  });
});
```

The .toggle(function, function, ... ) was removed from version 1.9

See the [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

A better approach: [Sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/579/)

```
$(function () {
   $("#clickme").click(function () {
       if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
       $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
   }else {
       $(this).parent().animate({right: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");}
   });
});
```

Comment: what happen if we change the width ?? its a wrong approach i guess

Comment: @av can you please check mine ? you approach is rite truly bt i guess we can make it better..i am not denying that your code is wrong bt we can make it little short..

Comment: @SachinRawal , yes you'rs is also good but ,i think i have a better approach..see my updated answer now.. no additional variables are used... and is compact too..

Comment: This is a bad approach in terms of cross platform/cross browser compatibility, as many people will have different screen sizes, therefore moving things horizontally using pixels is incredibly bad practice, better off not using pixels and using percentages.

Answer (score 3):

Toggle function is remove from 1.9 jquery..

You can try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/LU8En/57/

```
 var test= true;

    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if(test){
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }
                        else{
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});                
        }      
       test= !test;
```

Answer (score 1):

below sample can help u. thanks

### slide out from left

```
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>

#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    left:-280px;
}

#clickme {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
}

$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

### slide out from Right

```
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 20px
}

#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
}

$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, It helps to create slide out div for simple way

```
 <script>
         $(function(){
             $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
                 tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
                 pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',          //path to the image for the tab *required*
                 imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image *required*
                 imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image *required*    
                 tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
                 speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
                 action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
                 topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
                 fixedPosition: true,                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
                 onLoadSlideOut: true
             });
         });

         </script>
   <div class="slide-out-div"> 
        <a class="handle" href=""></a>
        <h3>San Web Corner</h3>
        <p>San Web Corner is one of the simple tutorial blog consist various tips and codes</p>
    </div>
```